# Real seamless SFTP tunneling / jump box

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sftp, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to set up a way for users to connect to the same "gateway server" for SSH/SFTP (SFTP a priority, SSH nice to have) and have that "gateway" server route the users to private servers inside my network identified by username and the private host they want to reach. This has to be a seamless user experience, i.e - no special config file setup, no flags for command line sessions, and no special setting in UI tools like FileZilla.

What I managed to do so far is add this block to my `sshd_config` file in the `gateway` server:

```
Match User someuser                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   ForceCommand sftp  -i /home/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa someuser@some_other_server
```

Now this works great when I'm doing this from a client machine:

```
ssh -i id_rsa someuser@gateway_server_machine
```

It will trigger the `ForceCommand` and give me an SFTP session to the `some_other_server` machine.

BUT, when I do

```
sftp -i id_rsa someuser@gateway_server_machine
```

the connection hangs and eventually terminates.

I need help figuring out what am I doing wrong here, or is there a better way to provide this kind of connection to my users.

Comment: Is "the private host they want to reach" fixed for each user? Or should each user choose one host on the fly somehow? For now your example uses `some_other_server` as a fixed string.

Comment: yes, fixed. we know the end machine address for each user

Comment: Do you expect the same client-side account access more than one server-side login? Each user should know the address of the gateway server anyway. How about making it `address:port` in the first place? Then you forward different ports on the gateway server to different machines, this should be easy. And that's it. Only if some client-side account needs to switch from one server-side login to another, they will need to reconfigure their client-side FileZilla or so (change port). Would this be a problem? The approach can work well for few users rather than few thousand though.

Comment: This is meant for many users, ports are my last resort...I need to do it smarter. Is there any reverse proxy recommended for this?

Comment: There is "smarter" and there is [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). But OK, I understand.

Comment: unfortunately this needs to be a seamless solution where multiple users can access one or more machines.

Comment: got answer from another post:
[answer in SU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510258/seamless-sftp-tunneling-jump-box/510278#510278)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been cross posted to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/510258/108618.